# How can i fix div container size & also extra content showing in 3 dots

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fix div container size & also not expanding the div container with its content, it is okay if extra content showing with 3 dots-Read more.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it stands now it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to improve it. Can you give us more context as to what you are trying to do? Perhaps show us an example of how you want your web-page to behave along with what you currently have written?

Answer (score 0):

is this your Answer ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.a {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.b {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.c {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: "----"; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The text-overflow Property</h1>

<p>The following two divs contains a text that will not fit in the box.</p>

<h2>text-overflow: clip (default):</h2>
<div class="a">Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b">Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: "----" (user defined string):</h2>
<div class="c">Hello world!</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The text-overflow: "<em>string</em>" only works in 
Firefox.</p>

</body>
</html>
```